# How do I tie OSX SSH User authentication to a custom 'users' mysql database?

Tags: mysql, ssh, authentication, mac-osx

We have a client intranet with client user credentials stored in a mysql database.

We are now trying to enabled SSH access to one of our servers for each client - where the authentication would come from our existing database.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

It sure looks like OS X uses PAM.  In that case you should be abe to use the [PAM-MySQL](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/) to perform any type of auth you want.  Out of the box OS X uses a pretty straightforward PAM config for sshd:

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
# sshd: auth account password session
auth       required       pam_nologin.so
auth       optional       pam_afpmount.so
auth       sufficient     pam_securityserver.so
auth       sufficient     pam_unix.so
auth       required       pam_deny.so
account    required       pam_securityserver.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_launchd.so
session    optional       pam_afpmount.so
```

I haven't set up PAM-MySQL before, but assuming it's similar to other external database PAM modules, there will be a config file that you use to select the db credentials, which tables should be used, etc.  Then you would insert `auth sufficient pam_mysql.so` just before the `pam_unix.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Theoretically that should be all you need.

Comment: I've confirmed that the pam_mysql project I linked to above will build just fine as long as you have the MySQL libraries installed.  And it looks like instead of a config file the various options are passed as arguments in the "pam.d/sshd" file.  I can't test any further without actually building up a dummy database, but it sure looks promising.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the reply but forgive me I'm a bit of a n00b.

The PAM-MySQL website isn't the best documented I've ever seen, do you have an example PAM config file (the one with the selection of authentication credentials)?

Comment: Take a look a the README file included in pam-mysql.  I was incorrect about the settings being stored in a config file; they're appended to the pam file like so:  "auth sufficient pam_mysql.so user=dbuser passwd=dbpasswd table=users usercolumn=myusers passwdcolumn=mypasswds".  There are several other options that can be used as well, all well described in the README file.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a couple ways you could do this:

1. Set up an Open Directory master, bind your server to it (or maybe that server would be the OD Master), and write some hooks for your client intranet that add/remote/update users in OD whenever there is a change
2. Write a Directory Services plug-in that is installed on your server which would talk to your MySQL database

For the 1st option, see Apple's [Mac OS X Server documentation](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html), esp. those relating to Open Directory. There is a `dscl` command which can be run from scripts to add/remove/update entries in Open Directory.

For the Directory Services option, see Apple's [Directory Services documentation](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/dirservices/), esp. the  [Writing Open Directory Plug-ins](http://developer.apple.com/networking/opendirectory.html) document.

There are probably other ways, but these are the two that jumped to mind.

Comment: Upvoted the PAM answer as that should be exponentially easier to implement than either of my suggestions.